# Game Engine - A workaround for sorting faces...?

Tags: game-engine

I know that there's  "Alpha sort" option to sort faces in the *suppossedly* correct way. But it doesn't work well sometimes. Now is that *sometime*.

I have some faces from an object that I need then to be rendered in front of other objects... and they appear behind. Faces to be in front are from a different object that the one (well, two) that are behind.

I know that OpenGL sort well faces... that are not translucent. Mines are all PNGs with alpha, Z-Transparency at 0.

Is there any workaround to achieve that?

This is in 3D View:

[image]

BGE (before EDIT1):

[image]

BGE (text solved with Alpha Clip but problems with ADD blend):

[image]

In fact, there are 5 layers that have to be in order: OSD, a plane with ADD blend type (hidden in screenshots), a plane with the red character (video), a rigged puppet (green jacket) and the background. Well... the dinosaur too :D.

EDIT1: I found that Alpha Clip is good for my needs, because those letters have 1bit alpha depth. But what about 8bits alpha depth images?

EDIT2: The plane with ADD blend is not rendering well. The problem now is with this object :/.

Comment: Just a heads up, I believe the game engine is **going away in 2.8**. What are you using it for? Could the new EEVEE engine work for you?

Comment: I know that GE won't be in 2.8 and no, EEVEE is not for my work (maybe not yet). Also, I had so many errors by trying UPBGE. That's why on 2.79, looking for "workarounds".

Comment: Hm. If you're trying to make something interactive, and you're worried about the discontinuation of the BGE, there's always [Blend4Web](https://www.blend4web.com).

Comment: As for the sorting thing, does the BGE support compositing multiple scenes together?

Comment: Yes, I know Blend4Web, but I can't migrate to it or to UBPBG or to Armory. Now, I need to stay in BGE. Oh... multiple scenes, I forgot about that! It can be the solution, thanks!

Comment: Finally, as @SilverWolf suggested me, I use a scene with OSD text and the ADD plane as overlay scene. Hey, you can write it as an answer.

Comment: Why don't you use Alpha Clip? It's not 'pretty' as Alpha Sort, but fixes any sorting issue you may find.

Comment: Joel, I said that Alpha Clip fixes something, but breaks other things, like the Add sort plane. Above it's shown.